# CSS box-shadow behaves differently on android phones compared to desktop and iOS

Tags: css

This box-shadow rule is working differently on android phones compared to desktop and iOS:

```css
box-shadow: inset 600px 300px 300px -300px #932121;
```

**Android:**
[image]

**Other devices:**
[image]

I prefer the look of the latter option, do you have any suggestion on how I could get it work?